# how to check installed gcc has some flag configured?

Tags: gcc, configuration, ubuntu-12.04, gcc4

How to check if the installed `gcc` has any of the flags enabled in configuration.

E.g. I want to check if the installed `gcc` has this `--enable-__cxa_atexit` flag enabled ?

I have Ubuntu 12.04 & gcc 4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `gcc --version -v`. It will output the `configure` invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one:

gcc -Q --help=target -march=native

Comment: Sorry.. this did't give the configuration flags.